# Is Nlog supported on Monotouch and Mono for Android?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, nlog

Is it possible to use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) on MonoTouch and Mono for Android?

Answer (score 3):

Generally the easiest way is to just try it.  Usually it takes very little to port a project to MonoTouch/Mono for Android.  I have done this with other libraries like JSON.Net, TinyIoC, etc.

I would recommend to download the source, add everything to a new MonoTouch/Mono for Android project, and set the `#if SILVERLIGHT` preprocessor directive in your project if they use it.  After that, it's just a matter of seeing what compiles.

Most common things I find to fix are missing RegexOptions or stuff in Linq Expressions, but all have easy replacements.